# Java utility method to combine two lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In .NET, there's an easy way to combine two delegates (.NET's version of a lambda).

Basically, you have:

```
LambdaType f1 = (a, b) => doSomething(a, b);
LambdaType f2 = (a, b) => doSomethingElse(a, b);
LambdaType combined = System.Delegate.Combine(f1, f2); 
// combined is equiv to: (a, b) => { f1.invoke(a, b); f2.invoke(a, b);};
```

Is there something like this in Java to combine two lambdas? Nothing comes to mind. It'd be a nice little utility, although it's honestly not too hard to define a second lambda that just invokes two (or more).

Comment: What does `Combine` do? Is it an `AND`, or an `OR`?

Comment: @kocko It's `andThen`, by the looks of it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik is correct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you talking about Java 8 lambdas? Because such utilities exist, for example:

```
Predicate<Foo> pred1 = f -> true; 
Predicate<Foo> pred2 = pred1.and(f -> false);
```

or

```
Function<Int,Int> func1 = x -> x + 1;
Function<Int,Int> func2 = func1.andThen(x -> x*2);
```

You should take a look at [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package because you will likely find the feature already available.

In your specific example you are not composing two functions, indeed, functionally speaking, you can't compose two functions that accept two arguments and return one argument (or void).

This because you are lacking a requirement: the [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of the first function must correspond to the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of the second function, otherwise composition can't be done.

What you are really doing here is sequentially calling two unrelated functions with same arguments. This problem can be solved by doing exactly the same thing:

```
BiConsumer<Foo,Bar> combination = (f,b) -> { doSomething(f,b); doSomethingElse(f,b); };
```

Comment: Can you show how this works for functions taking two arguments (and that are returning a result, or maybe are `void`)?

Comment: @Marco13: You can't compose two functions which have different codomain and domain. It just makes no sense, check my edit but you've already pointed out it in your answer.

Comment: You aren't necessarily composing them in the strict sense. `BiConsumer` is not a function, yet defines `andThen`.

Answer (score 3):

Since your request seem to incorporate functions which do not return anything, the appropriate Java 8 type would be `BiConsumer`. This allows you to do as you want:

```
BiConsumer<A,B> f1=(a,b) -> doSomething(a,b);
BiConsumer<A,B> f2=(a,b) -> doSomethingElse(a,b);
BiConsumer<A,B> combined = f1.andThen(f2);
```

This relies on the function type providing the factory methods for combined functions, rather than allowing arbitrary combinations, on the other hand, this allows to have meaningful combinations, like `and`/`or` for `Predicate`s which do something useful and understandable instead of just invoking the code of both functions and returning an arbitrary result.

Answer (score 0):

Function composition (also when applied to predicates) is probably not what you want: It means applying one lambda to *the return type of the other*. This has several implications. Particularly, you can not compose `doSomething(a,b)` and `doSomethingElse(a,b)` in this way, because there is simply no possible return type of either function to call the other.

As there also is no `LambdaType` in Java (unfortunately), you'll anyhow have to pick the specific function type. Written generically, you'll have two functions like this:

```
BiFunction<A,B,T> f0 = (a, b) -> doSomething(a, b); 
BiFunction<A,B,S> f1 = (a, b) -> doSomethingElse(a, b);
```

where `T` and `S` are the return types of `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`, respectively. In order to combine these and to create a function that executes both, you can simply write

```
BiFunction<A,B,Void> f = (a,b) -> {
    doSomething(a,b); doSomethingElse(a,b); return null;
};
```

(or whatever return type you would like...)